# How can I get Very Sleepy profiler to recognize function names in C++ binary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling, verysleepy

I have a tool that is mixed C#/managed C++/unmanaged C++ built with Visual Studio 2010. Code is actually spread across an .exe (I'll call it mybinary.exe) and a .dll (mylib.dll.)

I've set the build settings on the project for the dll and the exe in order to generate PDB files in release builds. I've made sure the PDB files are both in the same directory that the exe and pdb are in. But I still don't see the names of functions when I debug this program; I just see addresses. Here's the relevant excerpt of what I get in the little status bar at the bottom when I select the program in the first screen of Very Sleepy:

```
DBGHELP: mybinary.vshost - public symbols  
         C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Local\sleepy\vshost32-clr2.pdb\(long hex string)\vshost32-clr2.pdb
...
DBGHELP: No debug info for C:\myproj\mylib.dll.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\mylib.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\dll\mylib.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\symbols\dll\mylib.dbg - path not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\peastlund\AppData\Local\sleepy\mylib.dbg\4EF1F48B13c000\mylib.dbg not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\mylib.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\dll\mylib.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\symbols\dll\mylib.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\mylib.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\myproj\mylib.dll missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: mylib - public symbols  
         C:\myproj\mylib.pdb - unmatched
...
DBGHELP: MOD: mybinary.vshost
...
DBGHELP: mybinary - private symbols & lines 
         C:\myproj\mybinary.pdb
```

So it looks like there's a problem matching mylib.pdb to mylib.dll, for some reason I'm unclear on, but I'll note that I don't get proper addresses for functions that are from mybinary.exe either. I have a new computer with all-recent installs so this isn't a "some library is way outdated" problem.

Much appreciated if anyone can assist with this!

EDIT: Actually it turns out this is not specific to optimized code. Other profilers had some issues with optimized C++, which is why I switched to Very Sleepy, but on testing I realize now that with Very Sleepy I don't seem to be able to get function names even when I compile in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following:

1. You have set the symbols search path (tools->options) to your local path
2. Start your application first, then start the sleepy and profile
3. Stop profiling before application terminates

Comment: Set the symbols search path to what?